# Puppeteer with Prompt, ignoring rest of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, headless, puppeteer

I've managed to get my code to wait for the prompt, but for some reason it does not continue after receiving the prompt. The output is:

```
prompt: password:  
Command-line input received:
  password: password
```

Here's the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const prompt = require('prompt');
const url = 'some url';

var schema = {
  properties: {
    password: {
      hidden: true
    }
  }
};

prompt.start();

(async () => {
    var result = await new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        return prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {
            console.log('Command-line input received:');
            console.log('  password: ' + result.password);
            return result;
        })
    });
    console.log(result);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    /* truncated */
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to resolve the promise. I re-wrote the code a little bit to show the concept in practice.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const prompt = require('prompt');

var schema = {
    properties: {
        url: {
            hidden: false
        }
    }
};

prompt.start();

(async() => {
    var result = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        prompt.get(schema, function (err, result) {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(result.url);
    const title = await page.title();

    console.log(`${result.url} has title: ${title}`);

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    /* truncated */
})();
```

And running it will yield the following results.

```
▶ node prompt.js
prompt: url:  http://example.com
http://example.com has title: Example Domain

▶ node prompt.js
prompt: url:  http://google.com
http://google.com has title: Google
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I'll get back to you when I have access to the code